# How to write query with in a model with foreign key relation?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

```
class Categorie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
     return u'%s' % self.name


class GroupQuestion(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categorie, related_name='%(class)s_name_related', null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Group of Questions'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Group of Questions'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name


 class Question(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categorie, related_name='%(class)s_name_related', null=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(GroupQuestion, related_name='%(class)s_name_related')
    name = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #select_choice = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=QUESTION_CHOICES, null=True)
    positive_answer = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    negative_answer = models.PositiveIntegerField()

   def __unicode__(self):
       return u'%s' % self.name
```

I have these three model. When I pass category_id from my API wants to get QuestionGroups and Questions related to that group?

Some thing like this

"data": [
         {
            id:1
            name = ABC
            "question":[
                        {
                          "id":1
                          "name":ABC
                        }
                        {
                          "id":1
                          "name":ABC
                        }
                    ]
                }
               {
                  id:1
                  name = ABC
                  "question":[
                         {
                           "id":1
                           "name":ABC
                         }
                         {
                           "id":1
                           "name":ABC
                         }
                     ]
                 }
  }

I am new in django some can help me how to write query in view and how to serialize data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a [**nested serialization**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

---

You should create two serializers. One for your `GroupQuestion` model and one for your `Question` model. You will use in your `QuestionSerializer` *inside* your `GroupQuestionSerializer` in order to perform a *nested serialization*.

In your `serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import GroupQuestion, Question


# Serializer for the Question model
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'name')


# Serializer for the GroupQuestion model
class GroupQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question_name_related = QuestionSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    # The magic happens here ^
    # You use your QuestionSerializer inside your GroupQuestionSerializer
    # In order to serialize the related Questions for this GroupQuestion

    class Meta:
        model = GroupQuestion
        fields = ('id', 'question_name_related')
```

---

Then let's say you have a simple [`ListAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview) for listing your `GroupQuestion` entries.

In your `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import generics

from .models import GroupQuestion
from .serializers import GroupQuestionSerializer
# Import the serializer that we have just created


class GroupQuestionList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = GroupQuestionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        category_id = self.kwargs['category_id']
        category = generics.get_object_or_404(Categorie, id=category_id)

        return GroupQuestion.objects.filter(category=category)
```

This view will simply serialize *all* your `GroupQuestion` models, which have related `Categorie` with the given `id`.

---

Finally, map this view in your urls and when you access this endpoint, you should get the expected result.

In your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^groups/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.GroupQuestionList.as_view(), name='group_question_list')
]
```

*Note*: I am not sure that `question_name_related` is the valid `related_name` for the `Question` model in your `GroupQuestion`.